# Customize headers without fancyhdr

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, titlesec

I have strange, old book chapter to rewrite in LaTeX. The most iritating thing is the header. On odd pages the header should consist of the section name etc. But the problem is that if the page starts new section this sections name should appear in header (standard) and if the does not (the page is continuation of previous started section) and somewhere lower on this page the next section starts  then header should show the name of this continuation section (the name of the section that first line of text on current page belongs to).

I've googled a lot and stil have nothing. So simply - how to insert in the header the section name that the first line of text on current page belongs to instead of standard - the section name that starts somewhere lower on current page?

Comment: Is there a reason why you *don't* want to use `fancyhdr` to do this?

Comment: Ok, lets start even with fancyhdr, then I could just get rid of this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package offers `\toptitlemarks` to achieve the desired result; you could look at the file `ttlps.def` to see how this feature was implemented. A little example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
  \sethead{\toptitlemarks\thesection\ \sectiontitle}{}{}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\chapter{Here is a title that needs to wrap over several lines and has short words}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Test section one}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Test section two}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Test section three}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Test section four}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Test section five}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is in fact a complex problem, as explained in the TeXbook (p260), because you need emit two marks, one just before the title and other just after it -- in other words, sectioning commands have to be modified somehow, and this is what titlesec does. AFAIK, no other package (including fancyhdr, which doesn't modify the mark mechanism in sections) automates this layout. And being the author of titlesec, I can assure you it was far from trivial!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx -- hopefully, you will visit our site now and then and answer tricky questions about `titlesec`!

Comment: @lockstep Thanx. My time is sparse but I'll do my best.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this code in the preamble does what you need

```
\makeatletter
\def\rightmark{\expandafter\@rightmark\botmark\@empty\@empty}
\makeatother
```

EDIT. After rereading the question, it seems that I misunderstood, as the code puts in the header the last section title on the page.

What is needed is a local hack:

```
\stepcounter{section}{1}
\sectionmark{Title}
\addtocounter{section}{-1}
\section{Title}
```

Perhaps it's possible to check if a section title starts at the very top of the page and in this case issue the commands.

Comment: This doesn't change anything in my test document?

Comment: @Caramdir Yes, it does. On page 5 the header becomes *FIFTH SECTION*, while it's *FOURTH SECTION* without the code. However this doesn't answer the OP's question, unfortunately. Yours neither, I'd say. Try adding `\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}` after `\section{second section}`; in this way the third section title is at the top of the page, but the header still says *SECOND SECTION*.

Comment: And also when SECOND SECTION starts page, THIRD SECTION is somewhere lower on the same page in the header appers THIRD SECTION...

Comment: I see. And yes, I noticed that my solution was incorrect (it is already deleted).