# Trouble with titlesec

Tags: header-footer, two-column, double-sided, titlesec

I've been using `titlesec` for quite some time now and want to "pimp up my style" ;)

I've read [How to change header to list first section on page and not last section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20512/how-to-change-header-to-list-first-section-on-page-and-not-last-section/31182#31182) and tried to adapt the code for my purposes. I'm writing a twocolumn, twosided layout and would like my header to be formatted such that the header shows the context (i.e. section and subsection number and title) of the current two visible pages.

- On **left** pages the header should list:

  - print the section/subsection "enclosing" the *first* line of that page, if there's no subsection enclosing the first line print only the section
  - section *or* subsection *or* section **and** subsection may be printed on a previous page
- On **right** pages the header should list:

  - print the section/subsection "enclosing" the *last* line of that page, if there's no subsection enclosing the last line print only the section
  - section *or* subsection *or* section **and** subsection may be printed on a previous page

Let's have a look at my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[bf,pagestyles,raggedright]{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

%% to be used when odd pages are on the RIGHT HAND SIDE
\newpagestyle{main}{%
  \headrule
  \sethead[\thepage]% even-left
    []% even-center
    [\bfseries{\scriptsize \bottitlemarks\thesubsection$\:$\bottitlemarks\subsectiontitle} $\quad$ \bfseries{\bottitlemarks\thesection$\:$\bottitlemarks\sectiontitle}]% even-right
    {\bfseries{\toptitlemarks\thesection$\:$\toptitlemarks\sectiontitle} $\quad$ \bfseries{\scriptsize \toptitlemarks\thesubsection$\:$\toptitlemarks\subsectiontitle}}% odd-left
    {}% odd-center
    {\thepage}% odd-right
\setfoot[]% even-left
    [\thepage]% even-center
    []% even-right
    {}% odd-left
    {\thepage}% odd-center
    {}% odd-right
}

\newpagestyle{TitleMarks}{%
  \headrule
  \sethead[E:Top is~\toptitlemarks\thesection:\toptitlemarks\thesubsection]% even-left
    [E:First is~\firsttitlemarks\thesection:\firsttitlemarks\thesubsection]% even-center
    [E:Bottom is~\bottitlemarks\thesection:\bottitlemarks\thesubsection]% even-right
    {O:Top is~\toptitlemarks\thesection:\toptitlemarks\thesubsection}% odd-left
    {O:First is~\firsttitlemarks\thesection:\firsttitlemarks\thesubsection}% odd-center
    {O:Bottom is~\bottitlemarks\thesection:\bottitlemarks\thesubsection}% odd-right
\setfoot[][\thepage][]{}{\thepage}{}
}


\pagestyle{main}

\twocolumn

\begin{document}
\section{One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Two}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{TwoOne}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{TwoTwo}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{Three}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

And the result (don't mind the strange font for the title/header, that's an artifact of combining two pages in inkscape):

[image: result3]

On page one it states "2 Two" instead of "1 One" (section enclosing first line of text) [This depends on the "length" of secion one, once a part of section one continues into the second column the header switches to "1 One". **Edit:** After some further testing I've come to the conclusion that this a result of using **twocolumn** style, switching to onecolumn text resolves this part of the problem. However, this is not an option for me.] and on page two it prints "2.2 TwoTwo  2 Two" instead of "2.1 TwoOne  2 Two" (i.e. the section&subsection enclosing the first line of that page).

**Edit2:** Some further investigation yielded a sort-of-solution for the first problem described above. When using the `fixltx2e` package the header displays "0 Contents" (when there's a ToC) for `\toptitlemarks` and a "1 One" for `\firsttitlemarks` (which is sort-of what I expect yet not the results I'd like to have. Of course it is kind of pointless to tell the reader that on the page just before page one there's the ToC, i.e. this would require either using two pagestyles [one for page one which used `\firsttitlemarks` instead of `\topttitlemarks` and another one for all other pages]). However **I can not use `fixltx2e`** because I need `dblfloatfix` which conflicts with the former (well, more precisely, the former doesn't work anymore when both are loaded) -> this is no solution for me!

Is it possible to change that?

Comment: Dang! Now I triple checked my MWE only to find that I had a type in my code all along... changing `\toptitlemarks` <-> `\bottitlemarks` solves the problem in the MWE partially. Both problems are solved. However, a second requirement of mine doesn't work yet. Please bare with me, I will update the question shortly!

Comment: I've deleted the "old problem" section -- note that is still accessibe via the version history.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of the version history...

Answer (score 1):

Working through the requirements here, including the business about the fixes for the kernel, I think that everything does work if you take things a bit at a time

```
% Should be part of the kernel
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
% Required by the OP for 'other things'
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
% For filler
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{main}{%
  \sethead
    [\bottitlemarks\thesubsection\ \subsectiontitle]
    []
    [\bottitlemarks\thesection\ \sectiontitle]
    {\toptitlemarks\thesection\ \sectiontitle}
    {}
    {\toptitlemarks\thesubsection\ \subsectiontitle}%
}
\pagestyle{main}


\twocolumn

\begin{document}
\section{One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Two}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{TwoOne}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{TwoTwo}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{Three}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The result it:

- Page 1 has a left header '1 One' and no right header (first line of the page *is* a section, no enclosing subsection)
- Page 2 has left header '2.2 TwoTwo' and right header '2 Two' (last line of the page is in section two subsection two)
- Page 3 has left header '2 Two' and right header '2.2 TwoTwo' (first line of the page is in section two subsection two)

That matches up with what I (think) your requirements are ('left' and 'right' in the part before the example don't really agree with page number issues as described after!).