# Why do I see the first section title of a page in fancyhdr, not the last?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

While [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20512/how-to-change-header-to-list-first-section-on-page-and-not-last-section) asks how one can change from the default "show the **last section** of a page in the header" to "show the **first section** in the header" I have the reversed problem: The custom document class uses `fancyhdr` to set it's headers and seems to do magic to switch from the default. Now the requirement changes and I need the fancyhdr default behaviour back.

What can I do to have to have the **last section** of a double page in the header of odd pages?

I can't find anything wrong with the code in the custom class, so I wonder where
do they change the behaviour?

This starts a custom **section** called "Abschnitt" or "Ueberschrift 2":

```
\def\my@Abschnitt#1*[#2]#3{%        % ( Ueberschrift 2 )
...
  \markright{%                      %
    {%                              %
      \protect\my@markit\theMyAbschnitt\relax{#2}%
    }%                              %
  }%                                %
...
```

with `my@markit` being:

```
\def\my@markone{}%                      %
\def\my@marktwo{}%                      %
\def\my@markit#1\relax#2{%              %
  \gdef\my@markone{#1}%                 %
  \gdef\my@marktwo{#2}%                 %
}                                       %
```

and the `fancyhdr` configuration:

```
\newcommand\my@rightmark{%             
...
  \relax                            %
  \rightmark\relax                  % contains \my@markit
...
  \my@markone%    number
  \kern1em%       sep
...
  \my@marktwo%    text
...
}%
```

I skipped only formatting commands but magic logic here.

Therefore I can really see no evidence of changing the (supposedly) default behavior of `fancyhdr` from **last section** to **first section**. But, as a matter of fact, there it is. How can I undo that change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `\rightmark` prints the first right mark, while `\leftmark` prints the last left mark. So you are getting the default behaviour. Load the extramarks package it defines a `\lastrightmark` command:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Rightmark: first: \rightmark, last: \lastrightmark}
\begin{document}
abc
\markright{first}
\markright{second}
\markright{last}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Whow. Why didn't I see spot that? `extramarks` is what I needed.